# How to change QScrollbar's background color without changing the handle's shape?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qscrollbar

I am trying to change the background color of the scrollers in my `QGraphicsView` using stylesheet. But it also changes the handler's shape from a nice rounded bar to an ugly rectangle. Is it possible to retain the original shape? Here is the code:

```
QString style = R"( QScrollBar:vertical {
                            background: rgb(61,61,61);
                        }
                        QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
                            background: rgb(119,119,119);
                            min-width: 20px;
                        }

                     QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
                         background: none;
                     })";

myGraphicsView->setStyleSheet(style);
```

This is the original look:

[image: Nice rounded handle]

This is after setting the stylesheet (now the handle is rectangular):

[image: ugly rectangular handle]

Comment: Try by inheriting the qstyle that you used to style your application and then change the palette. In this [repository](https://github.com/Jorgen-VikingGod/Qt-Frameless-Window-DarkStyle) you can see a full working example on how to change the colors used starting from a given style by only changing the palete. Take a look at [DarkStyle.h](https://github.com/Jorgen-VikingGod/Qt-Frameless-Window-DarkStyle/blob/master/DarkStyle.h) and [DarkStyle.cpp](https://github.com/Jorgen-VikingGod/Qt-Frameless-Window-DarkStyle/blob/master/DarkStyle.cpp).

Comment: If you want to override the palette for only one type of widgets, you can overload `void QStyle::polish(QWidget *w)` and in the function check with a qobject_cast if it is the desired type of widget, then change the palette and call the implementation of your base-class style.

Comment: @apalomer I am able to find the scrollbar, but what parameters should I change in order to change the background color and the handle's color? 
void MyQProxyStyle::polish(QWidget* widget)
{
    QScrollBar* wig = qobject_cast<QScrollBar*>(widget);
    if (wig != nullptr)
    {
        qDebug() << "found a scrollbar";
        QPalette palette;
        palette.setColor(QPalette::Base, QColor(119, 119, 119));
        palette.setColor(QPalette::AlternateBase, QColor(61, 61, 61));
        palette.setColor(QPalette::Light, QColor(119, 119, 119));
        wig->setPalette(palette);
    }
}

Comment: can you share your style? I'm afraid this will be a combination of stylesheet and style maybe.

Comment: @apalomer, I ended up using your DarkStyle class and the darkstyle.qss. It works for the scroll bar, thanks :). But the strange thing is that the button background remains white in Light mode on mac.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is not my work.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late for the OP, but for others...

I would try adding more specific style for your handle.

I have the following in the application-level style-sheet that I managed to get working last year

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
border: 1px solid #5c5c5c; /* If this isn't specified... OMG */
/*background: yellow;*/
width: 50px;
margin: 35px 0 35px 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    /*background: green;*/
    min-height: 35px;
}
```

I suspect that with no style applied, the system default "native" style is used for the whole scrollbar. If you apply one element of style, then a (simple) default style is drawn explicitly, and your style is applied to that. So, if you only specify the background colour for your scrollbar, you'll get the default style for the handle. So, you want to specify most components of the handle to get it to look something like the native system one - border-style, color, border-radius...

I purged scroll bars from my app actually, and now I don't remember what happens if you don't specify the border - but it must have been pretty ugly ! (my aesthetic standards are minimal...)